# "TclError: can't find package Tktable" when importing Tktable.py in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, tktable

I am trying to import `Tktable` in Python 2.7.

I have put the `Tktable.py` file within my project folder. Last time, when I was using `Canopy`, it is working perfectly. After I changed to `PyCharm` and uninstalled `Canopy`, a lot of libs went wrong, I have successfully fixed all the others except `Tktable`.

Can anyone helped me?

Here is the error I got:

```
File "/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/project/Tktable.py", line 121, in __init__
    master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'Tktable')
TclError: can't find package Tktable
```

Answer (score 0):

The libraries available from PyCharm depend on your Project Interpreter.

A quick check is to use the Project View (Tool #1), and browse the `External Libraries`. If the library is not there, you can try to:

- Add the location of your library, via `Preferences.../Project Interpreter/Python Interpreters` (`paths` tab)
- (Re)install the library from PyCharm, again via `Python Interpreters` (`packages` tab).
- Set another interpreter for your project, if one of them has your library already.
- Install the library from outside PyCharm, for the right python version.